# How to split a file into smaller pieces before sending

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I get the following code to break up large files into smaller parts and send those parts, instead of sending the whole file? It fails to send large files (Tested with an ubuntu iso around 600mb)

```
...some code
# file transfer
    with open(sendFile, "rb") as f:
        while 1:
            fileData = f.read()
            if fileData == "": break
            # send file
            s.sendall(EncodeAES(cipher, fileData))
    f.close()
...more code
```

I tried with f.read(1024), but that didn't work.

Finally, when splitting up the files, I would need to be able to put the parts together again.

I'm also encrypting the files using PyCrypto, if that has any impact on what I'm trying to do. Guess it would be smartest to encrypt the seperate parts, instead of encrypting the whole file and then splitting that into parts.

Hope the above code is enough. If not, I'll update with more code.

Comment: do you have to do it in python? you could use the standard gnu `split` at the cli and transfer the resulting parts.

Comment: It seems to me that it should work with f.read(1024).  How does it fail exactly, can you give more details ?  BTW, no need to close the file at the end: the "with" keyword does it for you

Comment: I would prefer to do it in Python.

Using f.read(1024) gives me a lot of gibberish (Which is probably around 1024 bits of the encrypted file)

Comment: What does EncodeAES do? I googled it and saw an [example implementation](http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2009/aes-encryption-python-using-pycrypto/) that did `EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))`. If that's what you do, the b64 stuff could be the problem if it needs to pad at 1024. Can you skip the b64 and just send binary? If you keep the read() size on a 32 byte boundary (1024 is fine), it should work.

Comment: Would [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) be a viable option?

Comment: I don't see how this code could possibly work. Assuming `s` is a TCP, UDP, or Unix socket, you're not sending any lengths or delimiters, you're not closing the socket as soon as the send is done, etc. So, how does the other side know when it's received the whole file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I'm betting that your actual problem is not what you think it is, and it's the same reason your attempt to fix it by reading 1K at a time didn't help. Apologies if I'm wrong, and you already know this basic stuff.

You're trying to send your cipher text like this:

```
s.sendall(EncodeAES(cipher, fileData))
```

There is certainly no length information, no delimiter, etc. within this code. And you can't possibly be sending length data outside this function, because you don't know how long the ciphertext will be before getting to this code.

So, I'm guessing the other side is doing something like this:

```
data = s.recv(10*1024*1024)
with open(recvFile, "wb") as f:
    f.write(DecodeAES(cipher, data))
```

Since the receiver has no way of knowing where the encrypted file ends and the next encrypted file (or other message) begins, all it can do is try to receive "everything" and then decrypt it. But that could be half the file, or the file plus 6-1/2 other messages, or the leftover part of some previous message plus half the file, etc. TCP sockets are just streams of bytes, not sequences of separate messages. If you want to send messages, you have to build a protocol on top of TCP.

I'm guessing the reason you think it only fails with large files is that you're testing on localhost, or on a simple LAN. In that case, for smallish `send`s, there's a 99% chance that you will `recv` exactly as much as you sent. But once you get too big for one of the buffers along the way, it goes from working 99% of the time to 0% of the time, so you assume the problem is that you just can't send big files.

And the reason you think that breaking it into chunks of 1024 bytes gives you gibberish is that it means you're doing a whole bunch of messages in quick succession, making it much less likely that the send and recv calls will match up one-to-one. (Or this one may be even simpler—e.g., you didn't match the changes on the two sides, so you're not decrypting the same way you're encrypting.)

---

Whenever you're trying to send any kind of messages (files, commands, whatever) over the network, you need a message-based protocol. But TCP/IP is a byte-stream-based protocol. So, how do you handle that? You build a message protocol on top of the stream protocol.

The easiest way to do that is to take a protocol that's already been designed for your purpose, and that already has Python libraries for the client and either Python libraries or a stock daemon that you can just use as-is for the server. Some obvious examples for sending a file are FTP, TFTP, SCP, or HTTP. Or you can use a general-purpose protocol like netstring, JSON-RPC, or HTTP.

If you want to learn to design and implement protocols yourself, there are two basic approaches.

First, you can start with [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com), [monocle](https://github.com/saucelabs/monocle), [Tulip](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/), or some other framework that's designed to do all the tedious and hard-to-get-right stuff so you only have to write the part you care about: turning bytes into messages and messages into bytes.

Or you can go bottom-up, and build your protocol handler out of basic socket calls (or `asyncore` or something else similarly low-level). Here's a simple example:

```
def send_message(sock, msg):
    length = len(msg)
    if length >= (1 << 32):
        raise ValueError('Sorry, {} is too big to fit in a 4GB message'.format(length))
    sock.sendall(struct.pack('!I', length))
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_bytes(sock, length):
    buf = ''
    while len(buf) < length:
        received = sock.recv(4-len(buf))
        if not received:
            if not buf:
                return buf
            raise RuntimeError('Socket seems to have closed in mid-message')
        buf += received
    return buf

def recv_message(sock):
    length_buf = recv_bytes(sock, 4)
    length = struct.unpack('!I', buf)
    msg_buf = recv_bytes(sock, length)
    return msg_buf
```

Of course in real life, you don't want to do tiny little 4-byte reads, which means you need to save up a buffer across multiple calls to recv_bytes. More importantly, you usually want to turn the flow of control around, with a `Protocol` or `Decoder` object or callback or coroutine. You feed it with bytes, and it feeds something else with messages. (And likewise for the sending side, but that's always simpler.) By abstracting the protocol away from the socket, you can replace it with a completely different transport—a test driver (almost essential for debugging protocol handlers), a tunneling protocol, a socket tied to a `select`-style reactor (to handle multiple connections at the same time), etc.

Comment: Thank you. Execellent explanation that actually makes sense.

I guess I'll find a proper way to send these files :)

Comment: @MadsRC: Let me edit the answer to give a few different starting points.